# Tailwind css classes not working in Angular app

Tags: tailwind-css

i'm trying to adjust my styles in Angular app. In turn i'm trying to replace following:
html:

```
<div class="flex px-2 py-2 justify-between no-wrap">
```

scss:

```
.no-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

with tailwind classes:

```
<div class="flex px-2 py-2 justify-between overflow-hidden whitespace-no-wrap">
```

and removed all from .scss class.

And i see new added tailwind classes are not working, while looks like previos ones are. Am i doing something wrong?

UPD#1:

Once again - tailwind installed and working as expected, i'm experiencing issue with two new added classes `overflow-hidden whitespace-no-wrap`.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this installation procedure from [**tailwind**](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) step by step.

**Note:** import this to your `styles.scss`

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

then start your app again. It should work.

##### Edit::

According to your **UPD#1**:

[image: User's update #1 Screenshots]

---

There's no such class called `whitespace-no-wrap` it should be `whitespace-nowrap` as for `overflow-hidden` it works fine. Might try updating Tw version. Or, there's other class which overriding your tw class. Coz i find no issues with both classes .